# Restore old mc exit directory behavior

Tags: linux, bash, midnight-commander

I would like to have the OLD behavior of mc, when exiting meant that I will be at the directory where I was before I started mc. I'm only a user on the system, I suspect it's a Suse Linux. The `which mc` command outputs `/usr/bin/mc` which is an ELF executable file. The relevant part of my process tree looks like this after I started Midnight Commander:

```
root     20974  \_ sshd: user [priv]
user     20982  |   \_ sshd: user@pts/5
user     20985  |       \_ -bash
user     32211  |           \_ /usr/bin/mc -P /tmp/mc-user/mc.pwd.20985
user     32213  |               \_ bash -rcfile .bashrc
```

My suspicion is that bash (I think due to some configuration that I'm not aware of) reads `/tmp/mc-user/mc.pwd.20985` after `mc` exited and then changes its current directory to that directory.

Where is this configuration? How can I disable it?

Update: **@hlovdal inspired inquiry**

```
user@node01:/tmp> which mc
/usr/bin/mc
user@node01:/tmp> type mc
mc is a function
mc ()
{
    . /usr/share/mc/mc-wrapper.sh
}
```

Which means that on my system `mc` is a bash function, so I will need to search the location of this definition or somehow unset it. I placed this addition to help later visitors.

Comment: Should you only want this behavior occasionally, and have it change the directory most of the time, you could press Shift+F10 to quit. That key combination causes mc not to change the parent shell's directory, even if you have the alias or function in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system I have

```
$ type mc
mc is aliased to `. /usr/libexec/mc/mc-wrapper.sh'
$ cat /usr/libexec/mc/mc-wrapper.sh
MC_USER=`id | sed 's/[^(]*(//;s/).*//'`
MC_PWD_FILE="${TMPDIR-/tmp}/mc-$MC_USER/mc.pwd.$$"
/usr/bin/mc -P "$MC_PWD_FILE" "$@"

if test -r "$MC_PWD_FILE"; then
        MC_PWD="`cat "$MC_PWD_FILE"`"
        if test -n "$MC_PWD" && test -d "$MC_PWD"; then
                cd "$MC_PWD"
        fi
        unset MC_PWD
fi

rm -f "$MC_PWD_FILE"
unset MC_PWD_FILE
$
```

which seems to match your behaviour, so to disable changing directory after exit just disable the `mc` alias.

Comment: So in this case the answer would be `unalias mc` in `~/.bash_profile` or some similar place. For my case it would be `unset mc`. Thanks for the idea! I had no clue that `type` exists.